# How to monitor Caddy web server using Monit

Tags: systemd, monit, caddy

I have Installed Caddy server as a system service successfully using systemd. But I am unable to monitor Caddy by monit. ## Heading ##

Comment: Could you please provide more details (the exact steps you've already taken, commands executed, error messages etc.)?

Comment: I had followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-a-website-with-caddy-on-ubuntu-16-04)  to install caddy. Monit needs a pidfile to monitor a service but caddy does not makes a pid file, I have also try to creat pidfile by adding these line in caddy.service file
`PIDFile=/run/caddy.pid
ExecStart=/opt/caddy/caddy -agree="true" -pidfile="/run/caddy.pid" -conf="/opt/caddy/conf/main.conf" -log="/var/log/caddy/server.log"`

But caddy does not create pidfile

Answer (score 0):

Here is my unit :

```
# /etc/systemd/system/caddy.service
[Unit]
Description=Caddy HTTP/2 web server
Documentation=https://caddyserver.com/docs
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/srv/caddy
User=caddy
LimitNOFILE=8192
PIDFile=/srv/caddy/caddy.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/caddy -agree=true -conf=/etc/caddy/Caddyfile -pidfile=/srv/caddy/caddy.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR1 $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitInterval=600

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I use caddy version 0.10 and it does create a pidfile.